# React ENV & axios url fetching

Tags: reactjs, url, axios, environment-variables

Im currently fetching the env.production variable. with the local one, it works great, but when loading it to my webpage, im having some trouble.

its starting to call the url twice, etg:

```
 http://IPHERE/IPHERE:3000/onlinestate
```

instead of:

```
 http://IPHERE:3000/onlinestate
```

**Question: what am i doing wrong? it worked perfect with localhost.**

env.production :

```
DOMAIN=www.example.com
REACT_APP_MAINURL=IPHERE
REACT_APP_DATAURL=IPHERE:3000
REACT_APP_ONLINEURL=IPHERE:3000
```

calling it as:

```
axios
  .get(process.env.REACT_APP_DATAURL + `/onlinestate`, {
```

reference working localhost env:

```
DOMAIN=localhost
REACT_APP_MAINURL=localhost
REACT_APP_DATAURL=localhost:3000
```

**Edit:**

if i try to change it to:

```
REACT_APP_DATAURL = / or (nothing)
```

this occur:

```
 http://IPHERE/undefined/onlinestate
```

Edit 2:
production is named: `.env.production`
local:  `.env.local`

calling with `npm run-script build`

Comment: are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: yes i am @PrateekThapa

Comment: Try renaming your filename to `.env.production` and see if it works. And secondly, are you trying to use the `production` variable in your localhost with `yarn start`?

Comment: its named both .env.production and env.local . calling with npm run-script build

Comment: Can you console `process.env.NODE_ENV` in your app and run the build and what it gives? I don't think there should be an issue. CRA itself wires your environment variables to your App. And BTW, how are you running your build file?

Comment: when start ENV VARIABLE development, when build and test: ENV VARIABLE production

Comment: @PrateekThapa called as mentioned before. npm run-script build

Comment: And how are you testing it?

Comment: console.log("ENV VARIABLE",process.env.NODE_ENV); in app.js